# Select And Delete Multiple RecyclerView Items - AndroidX

Tags: java, android

I have written an app which shows a list of items in a recyclerview and have also added delete option in setOnLongClickListener, but now I wanna add an option to "setOnLongClickListener" where the item gets selected and then user can select as many items as they want and then delete them all together but can't seem to find out how.

This is my adapter:

```
public class TextTypingCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextTypingCustomAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private List<TextTypingObject> mTextTypingObjectList, mTextTypingObjectFilteredList;

    public TextTypingCustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<TextTypingObject> textTypingObjectList) {
        try {
            mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (mLayoutInflater == null) {
            try {
                mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mTextTypingObjectList = mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = textTypingObjectList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_text_typing, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        TextTypingObject textTypingObject = mTextTypingObjectFilteredList.get(i);

        if (textTypingObject != null) {
            viewHolder.onBindViewHolder(textTypingObject, i == mTextTypingObjectFilteredList.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTextTypingObjectFilteredList != null ? mTextTypingObjectFilteredList.size() : 0;
    }

    // ----

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView applicationNameTextView;
        ImageView applicationIconImageView;
        TextView dateTimeTextView;
        TextView textTypingTextView;
        TextView itemPackageNameSt;
        View dividerView;


        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // ----

            applicationNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_typing_application_name); // Text view
            applicationIconImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_typing_application_icon); // Image view
            dateTimeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_typing_date_time); // Text view
            textTypingTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_typing_text_typing); // Text view
            dividerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_clips_divider_view); // View
            itemPackageNameSt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content_input_event_package_name); // Text view
        }

        void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TextTypingObject textTypingObject, boolean isLastItem) {

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), TextTypingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", textTypingObject.getEventId());

                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            });

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {

                CFAlertDialog.Builder builder = new CFAlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                builder.setDialogStyle(CFAlertDialog.CFAlertStyle.ALERT);
                builder.setHeaderView(R.layout.more_dialog_typed_text);
                builder.setDialogBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191919"));
                builder.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                builder.setItems(new String[]{"Preview", "Delete"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int index) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();

                        switch (index) {
                            case 0: // "Preview"
                                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), TextTypingActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("id", textTypingObject.getEventId());

                                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                break;
                            case 1: // "Delete"
                                deleteInputEvent(itemView.getContext(), textTypingObject);
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                });
                builder.show();


                return true;
            });

            // ----

            applicationNameTextView.setText(textTypingObject.getName());
            applicationIconImageView.setImageDrawable(textTypingObject.getIcon());

            // ----

            String dateTime = null;

            if (!DateFormat.is24HourFormat(itemView.getContext())) {
                try {
                    dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a - E dd/MM/yy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date(textTypingObject.getTimestamp()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss - E dd/MM/yy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date(textTypingObject.getTimestamp()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // ----

            String textTyping = textTypingObject.getTextTyping();

            if (textTyping != null) {
                if (textTyping.isEmpty() || textTyping.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    textTyping = "Blank space(s)";

                    textTypingTextView.setTextColor(ResourceUtil.getColor(itemView.getContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
                }
            }

            // ----

            dateTimeTextView.setText(dateTime != null ? dateTime : itemView.getContext().getString(R.string.date_time) + ": N/A");
            textTypingTextView.setText(textTyping != null ? textTyping : itemView.getContext().getString(R.string.text_typing) + ": N/A");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                dividerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (isLastItem) {
                dividerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            String packageName = textTypingObject.getPackageName();

            if (packageName != null) {
                String itemPackageName = null;

                // ----

                PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
                try {
                    packageInfo = itemView.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (packageInfo != null) {
                    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;

                    if (applicationInfo != null) {
                        itemPackageName = applicationInfo.packageName;
                    }

                    // ----
                }

                // ----

                if (itemPackageName == null) {
                    itemPackageName = packageName;
                }

                // ----

                itemPackageNameSt.setText(itemPackageName);

            }



        }
    }

    // ----

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String query = constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null;

                // ----

                if (query != null && !query.isEmpty()) {
                    ArrayList<TextTypingObject> newFilteredTextTypingObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (TextTypingObject textTypingObject : mTextTypingObjectList) {
                        if (textTypingObject.getTextTyping().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(query.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) {
                            newFilteredTextTypingObjectArrayList.add(textTypingObject);

                        }

                    }
                    // ----

                    mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = newFilteredTextTypingObjectArrayList;
                } else {
                    mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = mTextTypingObjectList;
                }

                // ----

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mTextTypingObjectFilteredList;
                filterResults.count = mTextTypingObjectFilteredList.size();

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
                /*if (filterResults.count == 0) {
                    // There is no "notifyDataSetInvalidated()" method in RecyclerView.Adapter
                } else {*/
                mTextTypingObjectFilteredList = (ArrayList<TextTypingObject>) filterResults.values;

                // ----
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                /*}*/
            }
        };
    }

    private void deleteInputEvent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull TextTypingObject textTypingObject) {

        CFAlertDialog.Builder builder = new CFAlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setDialogStyle(CFAlertDialog.CFAlertStyle.ALERT)
                .setDialogBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#191919"))
                .setHeaderView(R.layout.delete_dialog)
                .addButton("Yes, delete",  Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#1976d3"), CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionStyle.POSITIVE, CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionAlignment.JUSTIFIED, (dialog, which) -> {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    Realm realm = null;
                    RealmResults<TypeViewTextChangedEventObject> mTypeViewTextChangedEventObjectRealmResults = null;
                    try {
                        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (realm != null && !realm.isClosed()) {
                        InputEventObject clipboardObject = null;
                        try {

                            clipboardObject = realm.where(InputEventObject.class).equalTo("id", textTypingObject.getEventId()).findFirst();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        if (clipboardObject != null) {
                            try {
                                realm.beginTransaction(); // Begin transaction

                                if (mTypeViewTextChangedEventObjectRealmResults != null) {
                                    mTypeViewTextChangedEventObjectRealmResults.deleteAllFromRealm();

                                    mTypeViewTextChangedEventObjectRealmResults = null;
                                }

                                clipboardObject.deleteFromRealm();

                                realm.commitTransaction(); // Commit transaction

                                // Refresh adapter
                                mTextTypingObjectList.remove(textTypingObject);
                                mTextTypingObjectFilteredList.remove(textTypingObject);

                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                // - Refresh adapter

                                // ----

                               // Toast.makeText(context, "Typed text deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                DynamicToast.make(context, "Deleted successfully",
                                        context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete),
                                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
                                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.successToast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                // ----

                              //  Toast.makeText(context, "Typed text could not be deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                DynamicToast.make(context, "Could not be deleted",
                                        context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24px),
                                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
                                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.errorToast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                           // Toast.makeText(context, "Typed text could not be deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            DynamicToast.make(context, "Could not be deleted",
                                    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_block_24px),
                                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white),
                                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.errorToast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                });

        builder.addButton(context.getString(android.R.string.no), Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionStyle.DEFAULT, CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionAlignment.JUSTIFIED, (dialog, which) -> {
            dialog.dismiss();
        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

This is my fragment:

```
public class TextTypingTabFragment extends Fragment implements TabLayoutFragmentPagerAdapter.ITabLayoutIconFragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = TextTypingTabFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private final TextTypingLoaderCallbacks mLoaderCallbacks = new TextTypingLoaderCallbacks();
    private TextTypingCustomAdapter mTextTypingCustomAdapter;

    private View mView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public TextTypingTabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // ----

    private Context getContextNonNull() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            return Objects.requireNonNull(getContext());
        } else {
            return getContext();
        }
    }

    // ----

    private int mItemCount = -1;
    private int mFirstVisibleItemPosition = -1, mFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "Fragment create");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(AppEnvr.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME_KEY, MainActivity.sSelectedPackageName);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, bundle, mLoaderCallbacks); // Init with 1

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // ----

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContextNonNull()).registerReceiver(mSelectedPackageNameChangedCustomReceiver, new IntentFilter(AppEnvr.ACTION_SELECTED_PACKAGE_NAME_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "Fragment resume");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(AppEnvr.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME_KEY, MainActivity.sSelectedPackageName);

        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, bundle, mLoaderCallbacks); // Restart with 1
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "Fragment pause");

        if (mTextTypingCustomAdapter != null) {
            mItemCount = mTextTypingCustomAdapter.getItemCount();
        }

        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            if (linearLayoutManager != null) {
                mFirstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                mFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LogUtil.d(TAG, "Fragment destroy");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContextNonNull()).unregisterReceiver(mSelectedPackageNameChangedCustomReceiver);
    }

    // ----

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text_typing_tab, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mView = view;
        mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text_typing_tab_progress_bar);
        mScrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text_typing_tab_scroll_view);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text_typing_tab_recycler_view);
    }

    // ----

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle() {
        return "History";
    }

    @Override
    public int getIcon() {
        return R.drawable.ic_typesave;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
        searchView.setQuery(null, true);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Text");

        try {
            Field mDrawable = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchHintIcon");
            mDrawable.setAccessible(true);
            Drawable drawable =  (Drawable) mDrawable.get(searchView);
            drawable.setTint(Color.DKGRAY);
            drawable.setTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView searchCloseIcon = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
        searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close);

        EditText searchEditText = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

        View v = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.drawerSecondaryText));

        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/regular.ttf");
        searchEditText.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
        searchEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.search_text));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

                if(mTextTypingCustomAdapter != null) {
                    Filter filter = mTextTypingCustomAdapter.getFilter();

                    if (filter != null) {
                        filter.filter(s);

                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                if(mTextTypingCustomAdapter != null) {
                    Filter filter = mTextTypingCustomAdapter.getFilter();

                    if (filter != null) {
                        filter.filter(s);

                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setActionView(searchView);

    }

    // ----

    private final BroadcastReceiver mSelectedPackageNameChangedCustomReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            LogUtil.d(TAG, "Receiver receive");

            // ----

            if (context == null || intent == null) {
                if (context == null) {
                    LogUtil.w(TAG, "Receiver receive: Context lack");
                }

                if (intent == null) {
                    LogUtil.w(TAG, "Receiver receive: Intent lack");
                }

                return;
            }

            // ----

            String intentAction = null;
            try {
                intentAction = intent.getAction();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogUtil.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                LogUtil.e(TAG, e.toString());

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (intentAction == null || !intentAction.equals(AppEnvr.ACTION_SELECTED_PACKAGE_NAME_CHANGED)) {
                if (intentAction == null) {
                    LogUtil.w(TAG, "Receiver receive: Intent action lack");
                } else if (!intentAction.equals(AppEnvr.ACTION_SELECTED_PACKAGE_NAME_CHANGED)) {
                    LogUtil.w(TAG, "Receiver receive: Intent action mismatch");
                }

                return;
            }

            // ----

            LogUtil.d(TAG, "Receiver receive: OK");

            // ----

            Bundle extras = null;
            try {
                extras = intent.getExtras();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogUtil.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                LogUtil.e(TAG, e.toString());

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (extras != null) {
                if (extras.containsKey(AppEnvr.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME_KEY)) {
                    String packageName = extras.getString(AppEnvr.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME_KEY, null);

                    // ----

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(AppEnvr.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME_KEY, packageName);

                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, bundle, mLoaderCallbacks); // Restart with 1
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // ----

    private final class TextTypingLoaderCallbacks implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<TextTypingObject>> {
        private String mPackageName = null;

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Loader<ArrayList<TextTypingObject>> onCreateLoader(int i, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            if (mScrollView != null) {
                mScrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (mRecyclerView != null) {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (mProgressBar != null) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            // ----

            if (bundle != null) {
                mPackageName = bundle.getString(AppEnvr.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME_KEY, null);
            }

            // ----

            return new TextTypingLoader(getContextNonNull(), mPackageName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<ArrayList<TextTypingObject>> loader, @Nullable ArrayList<TextTypingObject> textTypingObjectArrayList) {
            if (textTypingObjectArrayList != null && !textTypingObjectArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                mTextTypingCustomAdapter = new TextTypingCustomAdapter(getContextNonNull(), textTypingObjectArrayList);
            } else {
                if (mTextTypingCustomAdapter != null) {
                    mTextTypingCustomAdapter = null;
                }

                // ----

                if (mPackageName != null && MainActivity.sSelectedPackageName != null) {
                    mPackageName = null;
                    MainActivity.sSelectedPackageName = null;

                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, mLoaderCallbacks); // Restart with 1

                    return;
                }
            }

            // ----

            if (mProgressBar != null) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (mTextTypingCustomAdapter != null) {
                if (mRecyclerView != null) {
                    int scrollToPosition = -1;

                    // ----

                    if (mItemCount != -1 && mFirstVisibleItemPosition != -1) {
                        int newItemCount = mTextTypingCustomAdapter.getItemCount();

                        // ----

                        if (newItemCount == mItemCount) { // No added/removed events
                            scrollToPosition = mFirstVisibleItemPosition;
                        } else if (newItemCount > mItemCount) { // Added events found
                            if (mFirstVisibleItemPosition != 0) {
                                int addedEventsCount = newItemCount - mItemCount;

                                scrollToPosition = mFirstVisibleItemPosition + addedEventsCount;

                                // ----

                                if (addedEventsCount >= 1 && mFirstVisibleItemPosition >= 1) {
                                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mView, getContextNonNull().getString(R.string.new_events_found, addedEventsCount) + " (item)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    snackbar.setAction(getContextNonNull().getString(R.string.scroll), v -> mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0));
                                    snackbar.show();
                                }
                            }
                        } else /*if (newItemCount < mItemCount)*/ { // Removed events found
                            scrollToPosition = mFirstVisibleItemPosition;
                        }

                        // ----

                        mFirstVisibleItemPosition = -1;
                        mItemCount = -1;
                    }

                    // ----

                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mRecyclerView.getContext());
                    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
                    if (scrollToPosition != -1) {
                        linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(scrollToPosition);
                    }

                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTextTypingCustomAdapter);

                    // ----

                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // ----
                }
            } else {
                if (mScrollView != null) {
                    mScrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            // ----

            if (mPackageName != null) {
                mPackageName = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader loader) {
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a list of all selected item. When user long press on item save item position in the list and when user click on other items then add those items position too in the list. You can show delete option to user in action bar and when user clicks on that delete option delete all position item present in the list.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can do that (in code)? I'm new to android so not able to come up with any solution which works.